# Show that a recursive sequence formula is correct

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the Fibonacci numbers, denoted by {Fn}, with $$F_1=1, F_2=1$$and $$F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1}$$Let another another sequence be $$a_{n}=\frac{F_{2n-5}}{F_{2n-3}}$$ for $${n\ge3}$$
Now show that $$a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3-a_n}$$
Is this question as simple as plugging values into a(n) and a(n+1) and showing they are equal? Or is there a proper proof to show this recursive formula?

Comment: You can use induction.

Comment: Plugging $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is a fine proof if it works.  You should try it and see whether you can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove $a_{n+1}(3-a_n)=1$ or:
$$ \frac{F_{2n-3}}{F_{2n-1}}\cdot\frac{3F_{2n-3}-F_{2n-5}}{F_{2n-3}} = 1$$
or:
$$ 3 F_{2n-3} =  F_{2n-5} + F_{2n-1}. \tag{1}$$
The characteristic polynomial of the Fibonacci sequence is $x^2-x-1$, with roots $\varphi$ and $\bar{\varphi}$, hence the characteristic polynomial of the sequence $\{F_{2n}\}_{n\geq 0}$ or $\{F_{2n+1}\}_{n\geq 0}$ has roots $\varphi^2$ and $\bar{\varphi}^2$, so it is $x^2-3x+1$ and $(1)$ is proved.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying how you reached the characteristic polynomial of the sequence $${F_{2n}}_{n\ge0}$$ or $${F_{2n+1}}_{n\ge0}$$?

Comment: @AdamL: there are many ways to do that, for instance just to exploit that $$ F_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left(\varphi^n-\bar{\varphi}^n\right).$$

Comment: I am able to derive $a_{n+1}=\frac{F_{2n-3}}{F_{2n-1}}$ by substituting n+1 into the given formula for $a_n$, and also $a_{n+1}=\frac{F_{2n-3}}{3F_{2n-3}-F_{2n-5}}$ by substituting and rearranging the formula given for $a_{n+1}$. Is there a way to prove that $F_{2n-1}=3F_{2n-3}-F_{2n-5}$, thus proving that $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3-a_n}$?